# how can l Upload photo after editing. I don't want to save it as file but to update in photo view

Tags: photoeditorsdk

```java
mPhotoEditor.saveAsFile(filePath, new PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull String imagePath) {

        Log.e("PhotoEditor","Image Saved Successfully");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        Log.e("PhotoEditor","Failed to save Image");

    }

});
```

// Can someone help on how to upload, edit photo with stickers, texts like what's app
Methods show only to save it phone but me i want to edit and upload it directly. Thanks

All tried libraries but they are only saving in phone but me i want to update and upload directly like what's app